# SQL: How to split column by character count

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, recursive-query

I have one column with letters.  I want to split this column into chunks of three.  What SQL code for Microsoft would I need? I have read 'split my a special character' but I am not sure how to create a split by value where the split is not restricted to number of columns either.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
select t.*, substring(col, 1, 3), substring(col, 4, 3), substring(col, 7, 3) 
from table t
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this dynamically, as stated in the question, and have a query that creates just as many columns as needed, then you do need dynamic SQL.

Here is a solution that uses a recusive CTE to generate the query string.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

with cte as (
    select 
        1 pos, 
        cast('substring(code, 1, 3) col1' as nvarchar(max)) q, 
        max(len(code)) max_pos from mytable
    union all 
    select 
        pos + 1, 
        cast(
            q 
            + ', substring(code, ' + cast(pos * 3 + 1 as nvarchar(3)) 
            + ', 3) col' 
            + cast(pos + 1 as nvarchar(3)) 
        as nvarchar(max)), 
        max_pos
    from cte
    where pos < max_pos / 3
)
select @sql = N'select ' + q + ' from mytable' 
from cte 
where len(q) = (select max(len(q)) from cte);

select @sql sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

The anchor of the recursive query computes the length of the longest string in column `code`. Then, the recursive part generates a series of `substring()` expressions for each chunk of 3 characters, with dynamic column names like `col1`, `col2` and so on. You can then (debug and) execute that query string.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f4a66ef78f66bd87ca2601f27de96b44)**:

```
-- debug
| sql                                                                                                                                 |
| :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| select substring(code, 1, 3) col1, substring(code, 4, 3) col2, substring(code, 7, 3) col3, substring(code, 10, 3) col4 from mytable |

-- results
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
:--- | :--- | :--- | :---
ABC  | DEF  | GHI  |     
XYZ  | ABC  |      |     
JKL  | MNO  | PQR  | STU 
ABC  | DEF  |      |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, which does not need any generic SQL (as long as you can specify a maximum count of columns):

First we need to define a *mockup scenario* to simulate your issue

```sql
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourString VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('AB')
                       ,('ABC') 
                       ,('ABCDEFGHI') 
                       ,('XYZABC') 
                       ,('JKLMNOPQRSTU') 
                       ,('ABCDEF');
```

--We can set the chunk length generically. Try it with other values...

```
DECLARE @ChunkLength INT=3;
```

--The query

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT t.ID
          ,CONCAT('Col',A.Nmbr) AS ColumnName
          ,SUBSTRING(t.YourString,(A.Nmbr-1)*@ChunkLength + 1,@ChunkLength) AS Chunk
    FROM @tbl t
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP((LEN(t.YourString)+(@ChunkLength-1))/@ChunkLength) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values
    ) A(Nmbr)
) src   
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Chunk) FOR ColumnName IN(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6 /*add the maximum column count here*/)
) p;
```

The idea in short:

- By using an `APPLY` call we can create a *row-wise tally*. This will return multiple rows per input string. The row count is defined by the computed TOP-clause.
- We use the *row-wise tally* first to create a *column Name* and second as parameters in `SUBSTRING()`.
- Finally we can use `PIVOT` to return this as horizontal list.

One hint about generic result sets:

This might be kind of *religion*, but - at least in my point of view - I would prefer a **fix** resultset with a lot of empty columns, rather than a **generically defined** set. The consumer should know the result format in advance...

You might use exactly the same query as dynamically created SQL statement. The only thing you would need to change is the actual list of column names in the PIVOT's `IN`-clause.